# How can I use FabricJs with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, canvas, fabricjs

Im new in JS and want to rotate, change scale of images on canvas and coding in TypeScript using Fabric.js. as import to typescript is different with JavaScript so want to know how to import it to TypeScript. any links?

I install it like npm

> install --save @types/fabric

```
import {fabric} from 'fabric';
```

And after grunt files to js there show the error:

```
MacBook-Pro:someName mmmr$ grunt
(node:3965) ExperimentalWarning: The http2 module is an experimental API.
Running "typescript:test" (typescript) task
> src/someName.ts(20,26): error TS1147: Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.
> src/someName.ts(20,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fabric'.
> src/import.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
> src/import.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fabric'.
Warning: Task "typescript:test" failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any solutions for solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install fabric itself? `npm install --save fabric`

Comment: @Wernerson Yes I install it to project folder. 
+ fabric@2.4.2-b
updated 1 package and audited 15522 packages in 17.965s this is what I got after install

Answer (score 10):

Install using npm :-

```
npm install fabric --save
npm i --save-dev @types/fabric
```

Now import :-

```
import { fabric } from "fabric";
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [the test file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/fabric/test/import.ts), it looks like the expected import is:

```
import { fabric } from "fabric";
```

Comment: I tried to add import before module someName{} like  

import { fabric } from "fabric";

module someName {

}
but after add import, module name is going unreadable

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand either comment.  Can you give the exact error message you get?

Comment: src/import.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
src/import.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fabric'.

Comment: If you ran `npm install --save @types/fabric` successfully, then you shouldn't be getting the error `Cannot find module 'fabric'`.  Try adding the `--traceResolution` option to `tsc` to get more information, or if you can't figure it out, publish a repository of your project and I will look.  As the other error message says, if you want to use external modules, you have to specify the module output format to TypeScript.  If you don't want to use external modules, then remove the import and just use the `fabric` UMD global; the compiler should pick up the declaration from `@types/fabric`.

Comment: I tried to import fabric library by manually but when I try to grunt fabric ts, there is some error like :
> lib/fabric-impl.d.ts(2757,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
 and several times in different lines

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you just copied the `fabric-impl.d.ts` file into your project?  It would be better to get the module import working by doing the things I suggested.  If you want help with the manual copy approach, please add the full errors to the question.

Comment: I add full error which I got from terminal. and I didnt just copy >fabric-impl.d.ts file into my project I tried to add it to gruntfile.js

Comment: Based on the errors you posted, it looks like you need to set the `module` option and debug the module resolution using `--traceResolution` like I said before.

Comment: Im sorry but I have no idea how to use --traceResolution and where need to put it

Comment: When I am running `tsc` on the command line, I typically just add `--traceResolution` to the command line.  If you are using grunt, the place to add it depends on your grunt configuration file.  But if you are using a `tsconfig.json` file, you can just add `"traceResolution": true` to the `"compilerOptions"` section there.  This should produce a bunch of console output showing you where the compiler is looking for the `"fabric"` module.  Once again, if you get stuck, you can publish a repository of your project and I'll look at it myself.

Comment: I try it but nothing happened. do u have examples or projects using fabric in typescript?

Comment: I found [one such project](https://github.com/severjason/arcomage) in a [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?q=%22%40types%2Ffabric%22&type=Code).  It looks like it is [using the `fabric` global without importing](https://github.com/severjason/arcomage/blob/master/app/ts/components/canvas.ts).

Comment: thank for big support and help to try to find solution. I think for get familiar fabric.js and my code is takes more time than I make rotation and resize objects ))) so I'll try to do myself these. but .thank u a lot

Answer (score 1):

install `@types/fabric`

```bash
yarn add fabric
yarn add @types/fabric -D
```

then

```js
import { fabric } from "fabric";
```